# What is the って in 連れてってくれる?

Tags: grammar, particles, contractions, て-form

[ALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/) can give several examples of this, not only in `連れてって`:

> いつ私たちを湖に連れて**って**くれるの？ When are you going to take us to the lake?
>   これ、帰りに叔母さんとこ、持って**って**ちょうだい。Will you take this to your aunt on your way home from school?

The first て should be the one used after 連用形 of verb. But what is the `って` in the sentence?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- 連れる (終止形)
- 連れて (て form)
- 連れていく (+行く)
- 連れていって (+て form of 行く)
- 連れてって (contraction)

Answer (score 14):

It is a contracted form.

> いって → って